# How can I make a Spring Converter throw a custom exception instead of a ConversionFailedException?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, converters

I have a bunch of custom spring converters in my codebase something like:

```
public class ElasticSearchConverter implements Converter<RequestModel, ResponseModel> {
  @Override
  public final ResponseModel convert(RequestModel requestModel) {
    if(!requestModel.isValid()) {
      throw new ElasticSearchException("Request Model is not valid");
    }

    ... Implement converter
  }
}
```

I call those converters from a service by using the spring ConversionService

```
@Service
public class ElasticService {
  @Autowired
  private ConversionService conversionService;

  public ResponseModel getResponse(RequestModel requestModel) {

    //Throws ConversionFailedException instead of ElasticSearchException
    ResponseModel responseModel = conversionService.convert(requestModel, ResponseModel.class);

    return responseModel;
  }
}
```

My problem is when I throw my `ElasticSearchException` inside my `ElasticSearchConverter` it gets caught inside the spring `ConversionUtils` class and converted to a `ConversionFailedException`.  I want to catch the specific `ElasticSearchException` that I'm throwing in my converter.

How can I catch a specific exception from a spring `Converter` class in my service class?

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement class that will handle your Exceptions

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionTranslator {


    @ExceptionHandler(ConversionFailedException.class) //handle your Exception
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BadRequest) // Define the status you want to return
    @ResponseBody
    public ErrorDTO processElasticSearchException(ConversionFailedException ex) {
        return new ErrorDTO(); 
        /* Format your response as you need*/
    }
}
```

`@ControllerAdvice` "Classes with (the annotation) can be declared explicitly as Spring beans or auto-detected via classpath scanning" [show documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html)
`@ExceptionHandler`  defines the exception you want to catch
`@ResponseStatus` defines the http response status
`@ResponseBody` Serialize automatically response as json object

For my projects, i define an ErrorDTO to format the response, you can do the same and you will just have to construct your object and to return it
You can also put the code you want to execute into this method and rise an other exception if needed

Comment: Unfortunately because conversionService.convert only throws a ConversionFailedException this doesn't help me.  I do have a ControllerAdvice with @ExceptionHandler(ElasticSearchException.class) but it's never called because it only see the ConversionFailedException

Comment: Did you try to handle ConversionFailedException  isntead of ElasticSearchException?

Comment: Yea, that works.  But I'm trying to catch specific exceptions and handle them differently rather than generically catching a ConversionFailedException and converting that exception to the proper one.

Comment: I don't know if it cans help you but you can get the error message from the exception on parameter to have more details.
You can also catch the ConversionFailedException with a try catch block and throw your own exception into catch block

Comment: unfortunately that's what I'm trying to avoid, I'd like to catch each exception individually without having to re-throw

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple adapter class that wraps the Spring ConversionService.  In that class you would have a convert() method that delegates to the wrapped ConversionService method in a try/catch, catch the ConversionFailedException, inspect it (e.g. using getRootCause()) and rethrow as the exception of your choice.  Then for all classes that would otherwise use ConversionService you would use your wrapper class instead.

Comment: You can improve your answer by providing a code example, lots of people are too lazy or short on time to read an explanation.

Answer (score -1):

You're violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). It's **not** the converter's job to validate the converted object. If you're able to do the conversion successfully, then validation should be done separately using one of the ways described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#validation).

For example, consider you're converting an string to a latitude. If the string can be parsed into a double, the converter should be happy. If you want to validate that the double is within the range [-90,+90], you should do so in a validator and not the converter.

Not mixing up different concerns will help a lot  when you're handling exceptions, say in a `@ControllerAdvice`.

Comment: What happens if you want to convert something to an enum for example?

Comment: @LakatosGyula Spring can convert enums based on names, you don’t have to. Try it yourself.